# How do I add my output of max and min together to get the sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list = []
while True:
    n = int(input("Enter one whole number and press enter to continue or type -50 to stop the loop): "))
    if n == -50:
        break
    list.append(n)

print('-'*30)
print(list)
print("max number = {}".format(max(list)))
print("min number = {}".format(min(list)))
```

I just need to know how to add the max # and min # together to get one number. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it at all possible that all you want is:

```
max(list) + min(list)
```

Also, you shouldn't call your own variable `list`, as it shadows a built-in.